# Query with varying amount of variables

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a table with the three columns `timestamp`, `sensor_id` and `value`. Something like:

```
timestamp1,sensor1,value1
timestamp1,sensor2,value2
timestamp1,sensor3,value3
...
timestamp2,sensor1,value1
timestamp2,sensor2,value2
timestamp2,sensor3,value3
...
```

Now I need to write the content of this table to a textfile in the following format:

```
timestamp1,value1,value2,value3,...
timestamp2,value1,value2,value3,...
```

The user selects the timeframe and the sensors which should be written to the file. So the number of sensors varies. I guess it's easiest to fetch the values of all sensors in this timeframe and drop the ones from non-selected sensors in python.

Is this right or can I specify a query with a varying amount of variable?

Can I put up a query which gives the indicated formating (list all values with the same timestamp in the order of `sensor_id` behind the `timestamp`) right away?

I'm using the `mysql.connector`.

**Update**

```
sensor_clause = ','.join(selected_sensors)
query = """
        SELECT timestamp, group_concat(value) FROM measurements
        WHERE sensor_id in (%s) AND timestamp BETWEEN %s AND %s GROUP BY
        timestamp ORDER BY timestamp
        """
cursor.execute(query, (sensor_clause, start, stop))
data = cursor.fetchall()
print(cursor._executed)
```

Results in the query:

```
"SELECT timestamp, group_concat(value) FROM measurements WHERE sensor_id in ('1,2,4,5') AND timestamp BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-06-22' GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp"
```

And gives the result:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0), '-1.736'), (date....
```

Replacing `('1,2,4,5')` with `('1','2','4','5')` in a fixed query gives the desired result:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0), '-1.736,-1.375,6.843,7.87'), (date...
```

So now it's about getting the sensor_clause into proper formatting...

**Update 2**

Ashalynd's solution is working - Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
sensors = get_sensors()  #assume you have a method that returns a list
sensor_clause = ','.join(sensors) # if sensor_ids are numbers
OR
sensor_clause = "'"+ "','".join(sensors)+"'" # if sensor_ids are text values
# the result will look like 'sensor1','sensor2','sensor3'
timestamp_clause = get_timestamp_clause() #e.g. 'timestamp between <day1> and <day2>' etc

query = """SELECT timestamp, group_concat(value order by sensor_id) 
FROM <yourtable> WHERE sensor_id in (%s) 
AND %s GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp""" % ( sensor_clause, timestamp_clause )
```

(`order by` clause within `group_concat` ensures that values are listed in the same order)

The resulting query will look like:

```
SELECT timestamp, group_concat(value order by sensor_id) 
FROM <yourtable> WHERE sensor_id in (sensor1, sensor2, sensor3)
AND <timeclause> GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp;
```

This query will give you a list with   entries, which you can then output to wherever you like.

If you want to check which sensor ids were actually selected, you can do

```
SELECT timestamp, group_concat(concat_ws(',', sensor, value) order by sensor_id) 
FROM <yourtable>
WHERE sensor in (sensor1, sensor2, ....)
GROUP BY timestamp
```

Which will give you something like:

```
dd-mm-yyyy, "sensor1,value1,sensor2,value2"
dd-mm-yyyy, "sensor1,value1,sensor2,value2,sensor3,value3"
```

(assuming that e.g. at the first timestamp there were only 2 sensors producing values)

And then you can process these data further in your Python code.

Concretely, regarding the OP:

```
sensor_clause = ','.join(selected_sensors)
query = """
        SELECT timestamp, group_concat(value order by sensor_id) FROM measurements
        WHERE sensor_id in (%s) AND timestamp BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
        GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp
        """ % (sensor_clause, start, stop)
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
print(cursor._executed)
```

Why the OP version doesn't work: the reason is that sensor_clause is not one parameter, it's a sequence. It cannot be sent along as one parameter (otherwise it will be interpreted as string).

UPDATE: one other way to tackle the missing sensor values would be to create a small table which holds all possible values of sensors and do a left join with it, which would make missing values appear as NULL, e.g:

(assume that this small table is called sensors and it has one column, sensor_id)

```
query = """
            SELECT timestamp, group_concat(value order by s.sensor_id) 
            FROM  measurements m LEFT JOIN sensors s 
            ON m.sensor_id=s.sensor_id
            WHERE s.sensor_id in (%s) AND timestamp BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
            GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp
            """ % (sensor_clause, start, stop)
```

Comment: This great solution seems to work. However I'm stuck with the sensor clause. I'm coming with a list that prints like `['1', '2', '4', '5']`. Then I use `sensor_clause = "','".join(selected_sensors)` which prints like `1','2','4','5`. In the query it looks like `sensor_id in ('1\\',\\'2\\',\\'4\\',\\'5')`. The query then returns  `((datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0), '-1.736'), (datet...`- only the first sensor readings. If I put a fixed statement like `sensor_id between 1 and 5` in the query the output is like you described. The build command for the sensor_clause has to be changed- but how?

Comment: are your sensor IDs strings or numbers? If they are numbers (you can check it in MySQL with the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE <yourtable>;`), then you don't need quotes at all. But I have indeed not done it with the right Python syntax at first (mixed it with another language), going to fix the answer.

Comment: sensor is a smallint column.

Comment: With `sensor_clause = ','.join(selected_sensors)` I get `sensor_id in ('1,2,4,5')` in the query and the same return as above.

Comment: ah I got it. How does your "query" look, do you insert "sensor_clause" within quotes? you should not. So it should be `"WHERE sensor_id in (%s)" % sensor_clause` and not `"WHERE sensor_id in ('%s')" % sensor_clause`. Or do you have a different way or building up the query entirely?

Comment: I use it without quotes, have updated my inital question with the current code.

Comment: You should do exactly as I suggested :) What you do is supply the whole sequence as a parameter, which is wrong. Will update my answer once more with a variant that should work for you.

Comment: Still have a problem. The sensors aren't ordered correctly in the result. It's `timestamp, sensor1, sensor2` for one row and can be `timestamp, sensor2, sensor1` on the next row. I've added sorting of the `sensor_clause` (sensors now always come in ascending order) and tried adding `GROUP BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC, sensor_id ASC` but it remains unsorted. Any hint on this?

Comment: Updating my questions with the variant that has ordering by sensor_id in the grouping part. Also, consider the option when you output both sensor and value in the list, to make sure you know which sensors were selected after all.

Comment: One last question: Is there a way to add a placeholder for missing sensors? At the moment a row looks like `timestamp1,value1,value2,value3,... \n timestamp2,value1,value3,...` if sensor 2 was out of service at timestamp 2. This should be changed to `timestamp1,value1,value2,value3,...
timestamp2,value1,,value3,...` so the columns remain consistent.

Comment: It seems a bit tricky, may be in that case you just output the (sensor,value) pairs so that you know which sensors provide data (with `group_concat(concat_ws(',', sensor, value) order by sensor_id)` clause)

Comment: otoh there might be a variant when you create a table with all possible sensor ids , and then do a LEFT JOIN with it, substituting the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

```
select timestamp, 
case when sensor = sensor1 then value1 end as value1,
case when sensor =sensor2 then value2 end as value2,
case when sensor =sensor3 then value3 end as value3

from table
```

how about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of sensors, you can start with something like this:

```
SELECT timestamp, 
       MAX(sensor1) AS sensor1,
       MAX(sensor2) AS sensor2,
       MAX(sensor3) AS sensor3
FROM (
  SELECT timestamp, value AS sensor1, 0 AS sensor2, 0 AS sensor3 
    FROM datatable WHERE sensor='sensor1'
  UNION
  SELECT timestamp, 0 AS sensor1, sensor AS sensor2, 0 AS sensor3 
    FROM datatable WHERE sensor='sensor2'
  UNION
  SELECT timestamp, 0 AS sensor1, 0 AS sensor2, sensor AS sensor3 
    FROM datatable WHERE sensor='sensor3'
)Q1
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp
```